# Is 'skeptical' an adverbial accusative in this sentence?

Tags: parts-of-speech, predicative-complement, adverbials, subject-complement

I understand 'good' is an adverb meaning '[well](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good#dictionary-entry-3)' in this example sentence of 'start out' in the Merriam-Webster dictionary :

> The story started out [**good**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/start%20out), but I didn't like the ending.

But I think 'skeptical' is an adjective in the following quote because there are no definitions of it as an adverb in almost every dictionary :

> I saw that ability to alchemize emotions and opinions when I covered
> the queen on her visit to Ireland in 2011, the first by a British
> monarch in a century. It was impossible not to be impressed watching
> her speak Gaelic and offering regret about how Britain had made
> Ireland suffer, bowing her head at the scene of Bloody Sunday and the
> Garden of Remembrance, the sacred ground for slain Irish patriots.
>
> The Irish started out **[skeptical](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/01/11/opinion/sunday/meghan-markle-harry-royal-family.html)**, but by the end of her visit, many
> were calling her “Betty” on Twitter.

I wonder whether 'skeptical' is an adverbial accusative here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, "good" might be considered an adverb, although that use is relatively rare and often considered incorrect (or at least very informal). (See M-W's second "usage guide" [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good).) It would be more common to consider it a [predicate adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression). In your second example, "skeptical" is also a predicate adjective.

Note that predicate adjectives can appear after linking verbs:

> The Irish people are **skeptical**.

after intransitive verbs (as in your first example):

> The Irish people entered into the twentieth century **still subject to British rule**.

or even after transitive verbs (as in your second example):

> The Irish people began the Middle Ages **mostly pagan** but ended that era **largely Christian**.

I don't believe that you're using the term "[adverbial accusative](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adverbial_accusative)" correctly. It certainly wouldn't apply to either of your examples.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind and detailed explanantion.